# Equality in distribution preserved under continuous map

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for a simple proof of the following statement:

Let $X, Y$ be two real random variables, then
$$
X \stackrel{d}{=} Y \Rightarrow \forall f \text{ a. s. continouous}: f(X) \stackrel{d}{=} f(Y).
$$

It's a direct result of the continuous mapping theorem, but the proof I saw for CMT uses Portmanteau-Theorem, which is quite a heavy tool.

The proof I thought of uses:

$$
X \stackrel{d}{=} Y \Rightarrow \forall g \text{ a. s. continuous & bounded}: \mathbb{E}_X[g] = \mathbb{E}_Y[g],
$$
which is I obtained from the definition of weak convergence of pushforward measures, i.e. convergence in distribution. Then use that $(g \circ f)$ is a. s. continouous & bounded.

How can I extend the second statement to equivalence? Can this be derived more directly than arguing with trivial sequences of RVs?

Comment: If $X\overset{d}{=}Y$ then for any measurable function $f$, $f(X)\overset{d}{=}f(Y)$. It is straighforward because the distribution of $f(X)$ is the image of the distribution of $X$ by $f$, which is therefore also the image of the distribution of $Y$ by $f$, that is the distribution of $f(Y)$. $f$ does not need to be continuous

Comment: The right hand side of your first displayed equation looks odd: does it have a typo?

Comment: @Will I doubt it is true that a function that is almost sure continuous is Borel measurable. It is definitely Lebesgue measurable though, but this is more than we require from a random variable.